# How to make this basic JS bootstrap table to be able to add and delete

Tags: javascript, java, datatable

I am currently learning how to programming started with Javascript. To be specified, the CRUD. 
I figured how to make it editable, but the problem here is I can't figure out how to make this addable or deletable

This is my jquery dataset that appear on DataTable

```
var dataSet = [
                {
                    "id": "6231302001",
                    "name": "Ethan Hunt",
                    "gender": "Male",
                    "major": "CS",
                    "school": "IT"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6231502001",
                    "name": "Lara Croft",
                    "gender": "Female",
                    "major": "CE",
                    "school": "IT"
                }];

        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            deferRender: true,
            data: dataSet,
            columns: [
                { data: "id", title: "ID" },
                { data: "name", title: "Name" },
                { data: "gender", title: "Gender" },
                { data: "major", title: "Major" },
                { data: "school", title: "School" },
                { title: "Action", defaultContent: "<button id='btnDelete' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button> <button id='btnEdit' class='btn btn-warning'>Edit</button>", orderable: false }
            ]
        });
```

Problem 1: this is the delete function which deleted for me. However, the row comes back (with no array values) when I returned to the first page.(There are two pages.)

```
    $("#myTable tbody").on("click", "#btnDelete", function () {
        var record = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        record.id = dataSet.splice;
        record.name = dataSet.splice;
        record.gender = dataSet.splice;
        record.school = dataSet.splice;
        record.major = dataSet.splice;
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    });
```

Problem 2: I can't figure out how to add a row with input information for this table. I spent a week and got this unworkable code (not sure if this is the right path). it alerted this when I clicked

DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Requested unknown parameter 'id' for row 16, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Can anyone help?

```
        $("#btnAddSave").click(function () {
            table.row.add([{
                "id": "6231302016",
                "name": "Christiano Ronaldo",
                "gender": "Female",
                "major": "CE",
                "school": "IT",
        }]).draw(false);
        });
```

Comment: Problem 1: If you are using DB than you need to delete in DB as well otherwise on refresh it will show all values.

Comment: This is just a practicing with no DB connected. How can I solve this.

Comment: Normally you cant. Still all table data is in JS. If u refresh it will render again (i mean it will draw again).

Comment: what if I use JSON ,will it helps? or there is only way which is the DB

Comment: Ondelete also remove value from dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the delete function. By the way, to you know how to add a new set of info to this kind of array? I found only the basic of adding arrays throughout the internet. But there is no example of how to add my kind of array.

Comment: Get the selected row value and add to dataset.